# Pagination using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite my dynamic PHP pages under a Pagination System. I am on PHP environment. I tried some codes using .htaccess but not working properly.

**My Dynamic Pages:** `mysite/article.php?scid=9&page=1`

And `page=2`, `page=3` and so on.

**I want them as static:**

```
mysite/mobile-phone_technical-spec_google-nexus-1

mysite/mobile-phone_technical-spec_google-nexus-2
```

so on.
(Each id with different name)

Comment: What code did you try? Please include your attempts in the question so we can all learn something from why it didn't work.

Comment: I guess your id is different from the title, so mobile-phone_technical-spec_google-nexus should be mapped to id=9?

Comment: @BjørneMalmanger Yes..but how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I think there is 2 possible ways to solve this. Depending on where your able to modify code.

---

**A:**

I would modify article.php to accept title as a parameter. And inside article.php translate title to the ID you want.

```
article.php?title=mobile-phone_technical-spec_google-nexus&p=2
```

Then your rewrite rule could be:

```
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ article.php?title=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Example [article.php](http://pastebucket.com/50072) and [.htaccess](http://pastebucket.com/50075) added to pastebucket

**B:**

Second you could use [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html) in your .htaccess file to call a custom Perl script which will do your translation from title to ID.
create a script file in your filesystem (i.e. `getid.pl`) that returns id for title.

```
RewriteMap title2id prg:/www/bin/getid.pl 
RewriteRule ^mysite/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$  article.php?id=${title2id:$1}&p=$2
```

I think you should avoid Alt.B if you can, cause suboptimal scripts might give more risk and potential performance issues.

Comment: "I would modify article.php to accept title as a parameter. And inside article.php translate title to the ID you want" - How to do this?

Comment: @DV-Martin That depends what article.php really and which data is available. I assume there is a SQL Database in the background? A complete answer would require me to know your database and the contents of article.php. Is article.php something you've created yourselves?

Comment: Actually i was in iis server. Recently I shifted to php environment.
So i have to change my rewrite rules from web.config to .htaccess
The past web.config was working fine for me. 
But after convertion the .htaccess code does not working. Please check my past web.config code on the post i edited now.

Comment: Can you share your article.php on pastebin?

Comment: I made a new paste for you to give you a couple of hints on what you can do. It's only some kind of sudo code. [http://pastebucket.com/50005](http://pastebucket.com/50005)

Comment: @DV-Martin I have updated with links to pastebucket. Hope this is enough to accept my answer?